# OpenGL rotate not working correctly

Tags: opengl, graphics, rotation

I have 3 functions,which should perform a rotation for an triangle correctly, but it doesnt.My thoughts were, if i want to rotate my triangle around its center, i should translate the triangle origin to 0,0,0, which does `translateToOrigen`, then perform the rotation with `rotate`and then translate the triangle back to its orginal position, with `translateBacktoPosition` :

```
void Triangle::rotate(float angle,glm::vec3 axis) {
    translateToOrigen();
    modelMatrix = glm::rotate(modelMatrix, glm::radians(angle), axis);
    translateBacktoPosition();
}

void Triangle::translateToOrigen() {
    modelMatrix = glm::translate(modelMatrix, -_origen);
}

void Triangle::translateBacktoPosition() {
    modelMatrix = glm::translate(modelMatrix, _origen);
}
```

I call the `rotate`-Function like this :

```
t1.rotate(-90.0f, glm::vec3(0, 0, 1));
```

How i understand this, this should rotate my triangle around the z-axis with -90 degrees.
But what actually happens , is that my triangle got stretched and not be displayed at the correct position.
I already test the `translateToOrigen()` and `translateBacktoOrigen()`and they work very good, until i try to rotate.

I save all the matrices in the variable modelMatrix and when finished with translating and rotating , i send via uniform to the shader, where i multiply this matrix with my vertices.

I dont get what i am missing.

Comment: Please show the code that calls this functions. You might multiply in the wrong order.

Comment: `rotate` calls the functions, and i dont multiply wrong, since i am passing the whole matrix and then pass it to the shader, also i have tried to place the object directly in (0,0), and the rotation is still not working .Maybe its because i am in 2d space?I calculated the result of rotation matrix multplied with my vertices and its fine so maybe it problem with the projection?

Comment: Sorry. Overread the function. It's not about the correctness of the multiplication, but about their order.  You have to think about transformation from back to front, meaning that you have to exchange the two translate calls. In addition: glm takes degrees by default, not radians.

Comment: yes i am aware of that, but i thought it doesnt matter since, i calculate the modelmatrix before i upload it on the shader.still thx for your answer